# WinForm add new element to form between existing elements

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have the following form:

```
1) Label -> ComboBox
2) Label -> ComboBox
3) Label -> RadioBox
4) additional items
```

I want to insert a new ComboBox between **row 2 to row 3** and to move other elements.

How can i do it? is the best solution to create a **hidden** **ComboBox** and then make it visible? or should i create a dynamic ComboBox?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I used groupbox , and it did work... but i don't want to group unrelated items

Comment: I don't want each time i want to insert a new item between elements to group all other elements... i asked because maybe someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put my controls into a [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) and then you can simply insert new [RowStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.rowstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) into it.  And Columns for that matter, if need be.

As for moving things, you can always reassign the Row and Column indexes for the controls, effectively assigning them to new grid cells within the `TableLayoutPanel`.